# Why is this (testnet) transaction considered invalid?

Tags: testnet, raw-transaction

010000000180692cc54f9082c00a718123539396c42fd1a6d4a77eef677030483ce79fd3e70100000000ffffffff02b0040000000000001976a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ace05a0100000000001976a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ac00000000

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think it's invalid?  There data in the transaction looks ok to me but maybe your not signing it properly before transmitting?

Comment: It was an order of operations issue -- I was signing BEFORE specifying the fee.

Please add this is an answer to the question and I will mark it as such.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in the transaction looks ok. vout has value of .001 and you are leaving .0001 for a fee.  Maybe not signing it properly :)

bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 010000000180692cc54f9082c00a718123539396c42fd1a6d4a77eef677030483ce79fd3e70100000000ffffffff02b0040000000000001976a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ace05a0100000000001976a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ac00000000

```
{
  "txid": "16ee12e50d1ff805e91f34ab313d30009943c703fb142e9f457e0ea96a404e09",
  "size": 119,
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "e7d39fe73c48307067ef7ea7d4a6d12fc49693532381710ac082904fc52c6980",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00001200,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "msKbNQHuJoAdK4AKCof6ahoxzBsKG36UyE"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.00088800,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914817b776c02b9e0fe60163a170b0d72a194a463ef88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "msKbNQHuJoAdK4AKCof6ahoxzBsKG36UyE"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```